# Ubuntu 20.04 shutdown abnormally, gedit meets ../libgobject-2.0.so.0, undefined symbol: ffi_type_uint32, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Tags: python, shutdown, gedit

Ubuntu 20.04 was shut down abnormally due to the battery dying out. After restarting the system, I wanted to use gedit in the terminal but met

`gedit: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_uint32, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0`

However, I can use gedit without any problem if I launch it from the Show Applications menu. I can solve this problem by

`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7`

I found this solution at `https://github.com/elerac/EasyPySpin/issues/12`, but don't know why the problems happen and if there are some similar problems that I need to solve. How could I know if there are some similar problems?

I am asking this question because at first I also met other problems that can be solved by this solution but the outputs seems to have no relationship when using `python3 scipy`, `ROS1 rviz`, or even `ROS1 rosrun`, as the error messages are more different.

As it took me a lot of time to find this solution, could anyone provide a `guide` to check if the system or the configuration of the libraries are OK for the software, which means to check if the system is healthy like it was just installed?

My list to check is:

(1)Check Hardware, BIOS, and Image

As I can log in to the system and BIOS healthy check reports nothing, this part is okay for me.

(2)Check the filesystem and Disk: using fsck

As the only disk is used for the root filesystem, I can not know if the filesystem is healthy or not.

(3) Check the software environment by launching a test

I checked `python`, `scipy`, `ROS`, `rviz` and `gedit` then found a possible solution(not sure if there are still some other problems that persist), according to the error messages of `gedit`.

As there are many software and dependencies installed, I don't want to reinstall the whole system. Could anyone explain why this problem happened and provide a better `tool` or `guide` to solve this kind of problem easier? Thanks

Comment: Although the mentioned solution partly solves the problem, an error message `rviz: ../miniconda3/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libresource_retriever.so)` arise after I launch the `rviz`.